# There is no error in code, but not displaying error message when user click on invalid cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently working on a tic tac toe game using JS, and Ajax. I'm having trouble figuring out why the code isn't working for when a user click on a invalid spot on the game board. Everything works fine on the board, the user rotates from X and O after making click on the board. However, what I am trying to accomplish is that when a user click on a box that have been already taken by one of the X or O on the board it returns a error message. I can't get the logic to work for displaying the error message for when a user clicks on an invalid space that have been taken. I check the API to ensure the right data was being pass, when I log the data in the API it shows the correct index and value for the player when I click on the board. I think my issue is with either the rotate player from X and O logic but I essentially redid the entire code and still isn't getting the error message to display when I click on a taken cell on the board.

```
// start player with X
let playerStart = 'X'
// new game create handler
const onNewGame = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const form = event.target
  const data = getFormFields(form)
  // API call to make POST games
  api.newGame()
    .then(ui.onNewGameSuccess)
    .catch(ui.onNewGameFail)
}
const onGameBoard = (event) => {
  console.log('click works!')
  const boardIndex = $(event.target).data('index')
  const userClick = event.target
  const data = getFormFields(userClick)
  // store board cells into a variable
  const board = store.game.cells
  // set current player turns
  const playerTurn = playerStart
  // check if space empty on board using a loop
  const boardData = board[boardIndex]
  if (boardData === '') {
    // console.log('this space is empty')
    // check board data-index working
    // console.log(boardIndex)
    // rotate player from X and O
    if (playerTurn === 'X') {
      $(userClick).text('X')
      // add message for player turn change
      playerStart = 'O'
      $('#turn-display').text("It's O turn...")
    } else if (playerTurn === 'O') {
      $(userClick).text('O')
      playerStart = 'X'
      $('#turn-display').text("It's X turn...")
    }
  } else {
    $('#game-message').text('Sorry, invalid move. Try again.')
  }
  api.gameBoard(boardIndex, playerTurn)
    .then(ui.gameBoardSuccess)
    .catch(ui.gameBoardFail)
}
```

```
const gameBoard = (boardIndex, playerTurn) => {
  console.log(boardIndex)
  console.log(playerTurn)
  return $.ajax({
    url: config.apiUrl + '/games/' + store.game._id,
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + store.user.token
    },
    data: {
      game: {
        cell: {
          index: boardIndex,
          value: playerTurn
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're putting an X or O in your HTML document but you aren't also updating whatever `store.game.cells` is, which means the `boardData === ''` check is always true. To avoid this: 1) user interaction updates game state 2) game state is turned into HTML

Comment: The store.game.cells is what I used to pass data from the API after it is requested from the event handlers. In my API function, I pass through two param and  pass the  data where the store.game.cells is to be updated. Is that not where to update the game state after user interaction? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey Eric - would love to help, but you haven't provided some salient details. The only conditional code that tests for an exceptional condition is `if (boardData === '')` - we have to make a tremendous leap (giant guess) as to the contents of `boardData` because it depends upon two other variable assignments that you haven't fully disclosed. That's what led Chris G to the `store.game.cells` thing. While he was trying to help based upon what you provided, your response to him indicates we don't have enough to go on. Add some detail around that conditional test please.

Comment: Yeah, that API call might update the game state on the server, however where's the code that updates `store.game.cells`?

Comment: Thank you for your help again. I was able to get the code working after using your advise in updating the store.game.cells. Sorry, I should of gave you more details on the boardData assignment. What I did was create two variables one for the data index from html and the other was to get the empty array for the gameboard which is store.game.cells. boardData is just store.game.cells[index]. Thank you for your help, again.